# Протокол заседания кафедры

Tags: орфография, склонение, склонение-фамилий

Подскажите пожалуйста как с точки зрения русского языка правильно писать:Подготовка к публикации статьи Игнатов П.А., Ерофеев К.В. или подготовка к публикации статьи Игнатова П.А., Ерофеева К.В.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере от слова *статьи* задается вопрос к именам авторов: *чьей*/*кого*? То есть, имена собственные находятся в родительном падеже.

Из "Справочника по правописанию и литературной правке"<sup>1</sup> Розенталя §149·4:

> Русские и иноязычные фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный звук, склоняются, если относятся к мужчинам, и не склоняются, если относятся к женщинам. Частые отступления от правила (нескло­няемость мужских фамилий, оканчивающихся на согласный звук) наб­людаются в тех случаях, когда фамилия созвучна с названием животного или предмета неодушевленного, во избежание непривычных или курьезных сочетаний. Нередко в подобных случаях сохраняют фамилию в начальной форме или вносят изменения в данный тип скло­нения, например сохраняют в формах косвенных падежей беглый глас­ный звук.

Фамилии *Игнатов* и *Ерофеев*, относящиеся к мужчинам, в родительном падеже становятся *Игнатова* и *Ерофеева*:

*Подготовка к публикации статьи Игнатова П.А., Ерофеева К.В.*

---

1. Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке: Для работников печати. — 5-е изд., испр. — М.: Книга, 1989.